# How to show scrollbar on table with overflow-x: auto on iOS

Tags: css, ios, iphone, mobile, scrollbar

I made tables with overflow-x: auto. It works fine on Android devices. Then I put some style to scrollbar:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {-webkit-appearance: none; height: 4px; border: 1px solid #EB2B32 !important;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {background: #EB2B32 !important; border-radius: 10px;}
```

It works nice on Android and PC's. But on iOS the scrollbar is hidden, it doesn't even show up.

How to show it on iOS?

Thank you.

Comment: Wrap it in a container div and set overflow on that. Bootstrap does something simialr https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/#responsive-tables

Comment: Thank you. So if I put that table to div with overflow, the scrollbar will be visible on iOS?